# neo4j-python error

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a weird problem. I just started to use neo4j db and wanted to play a little bit

I downloaded there code from

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/python-shop-categories

In the example

```
import neo4j # works fine
```

but

```
from neo4j.util import Subreference # doesnt work
```

## error

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
 "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  exec code in run_globals
 File "/home/mohit/Documents/personal_pro/python-shop-categories/shop/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
   options.ui.start(*args, **params)
 File "/home/mohit/Documents/personal_pro/python-shop-categories/shop/__main__.py", line 49, in start
  exec("from shop.%sui import start" % (self.module,), environ)
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mohit/Documents/personal_pro/python-shop-categories/shop/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
   from neo4j.util import Subreference
 ImportError: cannot import name Subreference
```

So I am guessing everything is installed.. and set up.. how is it that one import works but the other doesnt works??

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's some old code that hasn't been updated in 2 years so it won't work.

Try the Bulbs Quickstart instead: http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/

- James

Answer (score 0):

For more updated examples, try http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/python-embedded-installation.html etc.